# Decoration fields with HTML in django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I try to decorate title in the model if entry is exclusive:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    ...
    title = models.CharField(u'Title', max_length=255)
    is_exclusive = models.BooleanField(u'Exclusive', default=False)
    def get_title(self):
        if self.is_exclusive:
           return u'%s <span class="exculsive">exculsive</span>' % self.title
        else:
           return self.title

    get_title.allow_tags = True
```

In the template, when I write `{{ entry.get_title }}` I get: `Some entry title <span class="exculsive">exclusive</span>` in the rendered version — the HTML tags are displayed, even though I set `allow_tags` to true on `get_title()`.

Comment: Personally, I don't feel it's ever appropriate to put HTML in a model. Your purposes would be better served with an inclusion tag or even a filter. Perhaps, I'm just too strict on the MVC side of things, but IMHO models should be all about data and nothing about how to represent that data.

Answer (score 1):

[Auto escaping documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/templates/#automatic-html-escaping).